# is_int returns false for negative values like "-10"?

Tags: php, integer

Does php's is_int function return `false` for negative numbers because integers in php are unsigned, or is there other behaviour that I'm missing? I'm trying to check if something is a whole number, and I don't want to rely on that behaviour of is_int (for the first part of the test) if it's doing something different.

Clarification: I know that `is_int` returns `false` for negative numbers, but I'm asking *why* because of this behaviour: `var_dump(intval("-10"))` prints `int(-10)`, and `var_dump(intval("10"))` prints `int(1)`, so both negative and positive values are considered integers, yet `is_int("-10")` returns false.

EDIT: Ok, sorry everyone, I got quite a bit confused about the behaviour of is_int and integers in general. I was thinking of it acting on a string with contents like "-10" when what I need is `is_numeric` on a string, or `is_int` on an integer itself. Thanks for the help.

Comment: "-10" is string not an integer. Also the PHP manual for Integers says `PHP does not support unsigned integers.` http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.integer.php

Comment: In case it's not clear yet: `is_int()` does *not* return `FALSE` for negative numbers, no matter how much you know it. It returns FALSE when the type of a variable is not integer, as [documented](http://php.net/is_int).

Comment: Thank you again; see my clarification about why I was getting confused.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It doesn't:

```
var_dump( is_int(-10) ); // bool(true)
```

Probably, it isn't a number to begin with:

```
var_dump( is_int('-10') ); // bool(false)
```

If so, try out [is_numeric()](http://php.net/is_numeric), which is designed for strings.

Comment: My DownVote: No matter this QA is old but this answere implies that `is_int( '10' )` would return true while the value starts with a number instead of a minus. But that's false while `is_int( )` validates only integers *without any conversion*.

Comment: @codekandis I can't see where the text is suggesting so but please feel free to contribute and edit the answer to clarify that point. If you don't have enough rep I believe you can still edit and your changes will be peer reviewed and hopefully approved.

Answer (score 3):

Why not test it for yourself?

```
<?php

var_dump(is_int(-1));
var_dump(is_int('-1'));
```

produces:

```
bool(true)
bool(false)
```

Comment: In addition, use an online php evaluator for simple tests - http://writecodeonline.com/php/

Comment: Yes, but `is_int("-10")` is working on a STRING that contains -10. Elsewhere in PHP it'd just auto-cast that string -10 into an actual numeric -10, but is_int works on the internal datatype, which is a string in this case.

Comment: @John Himmelman - I just use `php -a` on my computer for simple testing like that. I was just confusing the behaviour of `is_int` on strings with contents that "look like" integers and its behaviour on integers themselves.

Answer (score 1):

use

```
is_int(-10)
```

not

```
is_int("-10")
```

Answer (score 0):

I know this question is old, bu if someone need to check if a string represents an valid int, or, for example, a float, here is a simple script that will make that validation

```
$is_int = (is_int($val))||(((int)$val)&&(((int)$val)==((float)$val)&&((string)$val==$val))||$val==='0');
```

It works as a check. Forst, the simple is_int() function, then, it checks, for non zero values if the int conversion is equal to its float one, and finally, if the string is literally "0".

```
<?php
$val = 3;
$is_int = (is_int($val))||(((int)$val)&&(((int)$val)==((float)$val)&&((string)$val==$val))||$val==='0');
var_dump($is_int);
$val = 5.5;
$is_int = (is_int($val))||(((int)$val)&&(((int)$val)==((float)$val)&&((string)$val==$val))||$val==='0');
var_dump($is_int);
$val = 'hola';
$is_int = (is_int($val))||(((int)$val)&&(((int)$val)==((float)$val)&&((string)$val==$val))||$val==='0');
var_dump($is_int);
$val = '3';
$is_int = (is_int($val))||(((int)$val)&&(((int)$val)==((float)$val)&&((string)$val==$val))||$val==='0');
var_dump($is_int);
$val = '5.5';
$is_int = (is_int($val))||(((int)$val)&&(((int)$val)==((float)$val)&&((string)$val==$val))||$val==='0');
var_dump($is_int);
$val = '0';
$is_int = (is_int($val))||(((int)$val)&&(((int)$val)==((float)$val)&&((string)$val==$val))||$val==='0');
var_dump($is_int);
$val = 0;
$is_int = (is_int($val))||(((int)$val)&&(((int)$val)==((float)$val)&&((string)$val==$val))||$val==='0');
var_dump($is_int);
//bool(true) bool(false) bool(false) bool(true) bool(false) bool(true) bool(true)
```